# TortoiseGit Fail to install context menu on Windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7, uac, tortoisegit

I tried to install TortoiseGit on Windows 7.

Installation seemed successful, but TortoiseGit context menu does not show up after reboot.

What should I do to install TortoiseGit context menu?

P.S. 
1. msysgit is installed and successfully configured in TortoiseGit, if it's relevant. 
2. uac is not turned off.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is ...

You should install 64bit version TortoiseGit on a 64bit version Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since TortoiseGit 1.7.3, You must install 64bit version TortoiseGit on a Win64,

must NOT install 32bit version of Win64.

64bit version already includes 32bit shell extension dll so the context menu can show in a 32bit program.

Answer (score -1):

And install the mysysgit libraries for using tortoise on windows 7 x86_64
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/